# Mongoose data range query not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a search method which looks like this. (I have a lot of other code too for doing different kind of search but i am omitting that for simplicity)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.searchWithParams = function (modal, req, res, next) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var body = req.body;
    var orConditions = [];
    var andConditions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < body.searchParms.length; i++) {
        var param = body.searchParms[i];

        switch (modType) {
            case 'and':
                andConditions.push(param);
                break;
            case 'or':
                orConditions.push(param);
                break;
            default :
                throw new Error('Invalid mod type: ' + modType)
        }
    }
    var transalatedOrConditions = translateConditions(orConditions);
    var transalatedAndConditions = translateConditions(andConditions);

    var finalConditions = {};
    if (transalatedOrConditions.length > 0) {
        finalConditions['$or'] = transalatedOrConditions;
    }

    if (transalatedAndConditions.length > 0) {
        finalConditions['$and'] = transalatedAndConditions;
    }

    var query = modal.find(finalConditions);

    query.exec(function (err, results) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!results) return res.json(401);
        res.json(results);
    });
}

function translateConditions(conditions) {
    var translatedConditions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < conditions.length; i++) {
        var condition = conditions[i];
        var fieldName = condition.name;
        var fieldValue = condition.value;
        var searchType = condition.searchType;
        var dataType = condition.dataType;

        var translatedCondition = {};
        switch (searchType) {
            case 'range' :
                switch (dataType) {
                    case 'date':
                        if (!condition.minValue || !condition.maxValue) {
                            throw new Error('missing minValue and maxValue for range query')
                        }

                        translatedCondition[fieldName] = {$gt: new Date(condition.minValue), $lt: new Date(condition.maxValue)};
                        translatedConditions.push(translatedCondition);
                        break;

                    default :
                        throw new Error('Invalid datatype: ' + dataType)

                }
                break;
            default :
                throw new Error('Invalid search type: ' + searchType);
        }
    }

    return translatedConditions;
}
```

I give a search parameter like this

```
{
                "searchParms": [{
                    "name": "topics.modules.classes.startTime",
                    "minValue": "2014-12-31",
                    "maxValue": "2015-01-31",
                    "searchType": "range",
                    "dataType": "date",
                    "modType": "and"
                }
            ]
}
```

When the query is executed the condition it generates is like this

```
{"$and":[{"topics.modules.classes.startTime":{"$gt":"2014-12-31T00:00:00.000Z","$lt":"2015-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"}}]}
```

If I just execute the same query in the mongo console I get the results

```
    db.subjects.find({"$and":[{"topics.modules.classes.startTime":{"$gt":"2014-12-31T00:00:00.000Z","$lt":"2015-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"}}]});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55538211864ff2daf3dfc504"), "name" : "math", "topics" : [ { "name" : "math topic", "startTime" : "", "endTime" : "", "fee" : "", "modules" : [ { "name" : "math module", "startTime" : "", "endTime" : "", "fee" : "", "classes" : [ { "name" : "math class", "startTime" : "2015-01-01T20:59:00.000Z", "endTime" : "2015-01-01T20:59:00.000Z", "fee" : 300 } ] } ] } ], "teacher" : ObjectId("5552de1756c7e627ebceb1af") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5553832d864ff2daf3dfc505"), "name" : "math1", "topics" : [ { "name" : "math1 topic", "startTime" : "", "endTime" : "", "fee" : "", "modules" : [ { "name" : "math1 module", "startTime" : "", "endTime" : "", "fee" : "", "classes" : [ { "name" : "math1 class", "startTime" : "2015-01-01T20:59:00.000Z", "endTime" : "2015-02-01T20:59:00.000Z", "fee" : 3001 } ] } ] } ], "teacher" : ObjectId("5552de1756c7e627ebceb1af") }
```

But somehow the method returns me nothing. The range query for other type of data like number (code is omitted) is working fine. How is it that the same condition works in mongo console but not in the server code. Any insight will be greatly helpful.